# download and play stream audio in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i need to play sound with user click on the preview icon .

this is my html code :

```
<audio controls>
    <source [src]="fileSource" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

this this is ts code :

```
fileSource: any;

ngOnInit(): void {
if (typeof this.data.src === 'number') {
  this.getImageFromService();
  }
}

     createImageFromBlob(image: Blob): void {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
      this.fileSource = reader.result;
    }, false);

    if (image) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(image);
    }
  }

  getImageFromService(): void {

    this.isLoading = true;
    this.postFileService.downloadFile(this.data.src).subscribe(data => {
      this.createImageFromBlob(data);
      this.isLoading = false;
    }, error => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

and this is my service :

```
   downloadFile(id: number): Observable<Blob> {
    const URL = `${this.appConfig.apiEndpoint + '/PostFileContent/DownloadFile/' + id}`;

    return this.http.get(URL, { responseType: 'blob' });
}
```

now my prolem is this :

i need to when click the preview icon T open the modal dialog box and play audio .

when i click on the preview icon the file is downloaded but it not play .

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this ???**

Comment: have you heard downloaded audio file ?

Comment: @mayurkukadiya no

Comment: Try to add "autoplay" attribute inside audio tag like this : <audio controls autoplay>

Comment: @mayurkukadiya no its not work

Comment: Can you add a plnkr or codepen?

Comment: could you please tell did my answer helped or worked?

Answer (score 2):

Following code will work for playing audio automatically file which was retrieved from backend(node.js).

**angular.html**

```
<audio controls>
  <source  type="audio/mpeg"  [src]="fileSource" >
</audio>
```

**angualr.ts**

```
// mention your backend url directly here like below
fileSource:any = 'http://localhost:1234/getAudioFile';
```

**node-backend-code**

```
  app.use('/getAudioFile',function(req,res,next){
  // i stored sample mp3 file in my local directory
  var filePath = path1.join(__dirname, './sample.mp3');
  var stat = fileSystem.statSync(filePath);

  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
    'Content-Length': stat.size
  });

  var readStream = fileSystem.createReadStream(filePath);
  // We replaced all the event handlers with a simple call to readStream.pipe()
  readStream.pipe(res);
  // res.send("this is audio ");
  next();
});
```

**Note**:: Make sure that you get directly audio file from backend(irrespective of node or java).